# Update packages policy on RHEL6

Tags: docker, rhel, epel

Do you know how frequently RHEL6 EPEL packages are updated ? Is there a way to track it in order to have timeline?
I am mainly interested in docker-io package

At the moment, EPEL package is set with **docker-io-1.4.1-3.el6.x86_64**. However, docker 1.5.0 has been released since **2015-02-03**

EPEL package version: https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/docker-io.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have fedora referential with a more recent docker: https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/testing/6/SRPMS/: `docker-io-1.5.0-1.el6.src.rpm`

As mentioned in "[issues 7968](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7968#issuecomment-55101241)":

> Docker 1.x is in the EPEL testing repository.
>   You can enable the testing repository and install with:

```
yum --enablerepo epel-testing install docker-io
```

> EPEL may not have the latest Docker version.
>   You'll need to install via our packages or raise the issue with the [downstream EPEL team](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#Is_EPEL_.22upstream.22_or_.22an_official_package_repository.22_.28like_Fedora_Extras_was.29.3F).

That means only the [EPEL maintainers](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL_Package_Maintainers) would have more visibility on the update calendar for this package.

Comment: I am sorry but the question is rather to understand when i will be able to see docker-io package within EPEL repos for RHEL6 and if there is a way to track it. PS: docker is another package not related to docker-io on RHEL6

Comment: @FlorentValdelievre OK, I have rewritten the answer accordingly.